# Minimizing a diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation, exponential-diophantine-equations

If we are given $x,y$ both integers where $x>y>1$ for the expression $$(x^{\frac{a}{b}} - y)\cdot y^{b}$$
Is there any way to find integer values for a,b in which this expression is minimal and positive. I'm not sure if it is possible or if the answer can lie at infinity. So any feedback would be helpful.

Edit: x,y,a,b are all positive integers

Comment: I am new to this topic, so if you could please explain what you mean by 'minimal'...

Comment: If $y=1$ then it's easy to see that there is no minimum. Are $x,y$ meant to be integers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson My **blind guess** is that the only constraint on $x,y$ is that $0 < y < x$, which means that the algorithm is probably affected based on whether $y < 1, y = 1,$ or $y > 1.$  **To the OP**: Is it your intent that $a,b$ are required to be positive, or are negative integers also allowed to be considered?

Comment: Re Gerry Myerson's comment, when $y = 1$, since $$\left(x^{ [a/b]} ~-~ y\right) \times y^b$$ is required to be positive, you can have the expression get as close to zero as you want.

Comment: @Spectre Minimal as in the smallest value the expression can have according to the constraints

Comment: @Nimish Thanks !

Comment: If y =< 1 the problem kinda becomes meaningless, I edited to make sure that 1<y<x

Comment: WolframAlpha offers a solution [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+%28x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%7D+-+y%29%5Ccdot+y%5E%7Bb%7D).